# ¿Como podria hacer un buscador en laravel 5.1?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Buenas amigos, la cuestion es sencilla, necesito hacer un buscador en laravel pero la forma en como la estoy haciendo, me complica un poco la cosa porque estoy haciendo lo siguient:

actualmente en el controlador tengo esto:

```
public function index(Request $request)
{

    $events = Event::Events();

    return view('event.index', compact('events'));
}
```

Lo cual lo mando al index y me lista las categorias con el metodo:

```
public static function Events(){
    return DB::table('events')
    ->join('categories', 'categories.id', '=', 'events.category_id')
    ->select('events.*', 'categories.name_cat')
    ->get();
}
```

la cuestion es que estoy intentando hacer con un scope el buscador pero el problema es que tengo el metodo que necesito para listar las categorias, ya que tiene la consulta y no se como usar el scope y tambien el metodo Events, como pienso hacerlo es algo asi:

```
public function index(Request $request)
{

    $events = Event::name($request->get('name_eve'))->orderBy('id','DESC')->paginate(2);
    return view('event.index', compact('events'));
}
```

Lo cual me funciona, pero el problema es que no me muestra la categoria en el index porque necesito utilizar el metodo Events.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Asumiendo que tengas creados los modelos `Event` y `Category`, y que su relación es de uno a muchos, podrías solucionarlo fácilmente gracias a las propiedades dinámicas de Eloquent y a Eager loading.

Lo primero es que veo que el método `Events()` es innecesario, en vez de crear y usar ese método, simplemente puedes hacer (asumiendo que la relación en el modelo Event se llame 'category':

```
$events = Event::with('category')->all();
```

Por lo que veo creo que vas a hacer un scope para buscar por nombre del evento, que sería algo así:

```
public function scopeName($query, $name)
{
    return $query->where('name', $name);
}
```

Cargarías la relación de las categorías de esta manera:

```
$events = Event::with('category')->name($request->get('name_eve'))->orderBy('id','DESC')->paginate(2);
```

(Aunque tengo una duda y no recuerdo si se puede hacer Eager Loading dentro del scope, por eso lo dejé por fuera)

El nombre de la categoría lo obtendrías como una propiedad del objeto evento:

```
$event->category->name_cat
```

Comment: Excelente justo me funciono!